# CTS (Compatibility Test Suite) is for Hardware Or Software Compatibility?

Tags: android, performance-testing, cts

Any one can tell CTS (Compatibility Test Suite) is for Hardware or Software Compatibility?

Answer (score 0):

It is for software compatibility. Areas covered are listed here

https://source.android.com/compatibility/cts-intro.html#areas-covered

Answer (score 0):

CTS Testing basically software compatibility over hardware. In other words Android is developed using CDD Doc Testing this requirement is done by CTS